# Angular2 removed hash from URL on Tomcat

Tags: url-rewriting, tomcat7, angular2-routing

We have Angular 2 app, we removed `HashLocationStrategy` from `providers` for routing without hash ('#').

It works fine when we run project using `ng server`.

However when we generate build and deployed build on `apache-tomcat-7.0.67` and URL with route [(e.g) localhost:8080/dist/login] here `login is route`, then when we refresh it returns with `404 page`.

I tried solution suggested in this link :
[Apache Tomcat Rewrite Rules](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/apache-tomcat-rewrite-rules-example/)

But still I cant find any working solution for my case as of this is angular2 application.

Please guide for better solution without using any external url-rewrite library like nginx etc.

Thank you.